# C some pointer questions

Tags: c, pointers

can somebody explain these answers? I can understand 2. , 4. but the rest i can not

```
int a[ ] ={2,4,3,1,10,5,9,6,8,7};
int *pa = &a[4],*pb = &a[1];

What is the value of the below?
1.*(a + 3)
2.*pb-*pa
3.pb[3]
4.*pa + 5
5.*(pa-2)
6.pa[4] 


Answer:

1.*(a + 3)=1
2.*pb-*pa=-6
3.pb[3]=10
4.*pa + 5=15
5.*(pa-2)=3
6.pa[4]=8
```

Comment: What do you think the answers should be, and why?

Comment: i know i should be reading about it, but right now in 1 hour i have to take an exam and i found this question was once given by the professor and i need to understand it. and he has never mentioned the *(a+3) syntax. also i cannot understand the pb[number] since it should be a pointer not an array...

Comment: *You* have to ask an actual question here. If you have a question about this problem, you have to tell us what it is.

Comment: You should have studied more, if you don't want to learn enough to actually work at it, why do you expect people to help you.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed, it is a real question even if the person has demonstrated a total lack of knowledge about the most basic concepts in c

Comment: how these 3 syntaxes work...*(pa-2) *(a + 3) pb[3]

Comment: look up pointer arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x[y]` is equivalent to `y[x]`, which is equivalent to `*(x+y)` or `*(y+x)`. So `*(a+3)` is equivalent to `a[3]` or `3[a]`.

Comment: i still don't get pa[4] and *(pa-2);

Comment: `pa` is a pointer to `a[4]`, so `pa[4]` is the same as `a[4+4]`, or `a[8]`. `pa-2` is a pointer to `a[2]`, so `*(pa-2)` is the same as `a[4-2]`, or `a[2]`. This exercise is basically about playing with pointers, memory addresses and fetching the values stored in those addresses.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Careful there, `x[y]` is only equivalent to `y[x]` if `sizeof(*x) == sizeof(*y) == 1`. The offset is always multiplied by the type size both when operating arrays or doing arithmetics with pointers.

Comment: @Havenard: If you're doing `x[y]` and `y[x]` at all, one of those guys has to be a number, they can't both be pointers.